# Can authors retell their own stories in different ways?

Tags: creative-writing, plot, publishing, originality, story

This probably sounds like a stupid question, but I have an idea to take the love story subplot from my fantasy story and retell it in the real world, without any magic or fantasy in it. I love the concept and it sounds fun to write, but is this something that would be publishable if my fantasy story gets published? As in, will publishers think it’s lazy or redundant, or might it be okay since it’s going after a somewhat different audience?

Ultimately, the stories would end up diverging, but it would be the same starter concept with some details that are VERY obviously pulling from the same idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. There are multiple recent examples of authors having done this:

- Stephanie Meyer wrote *Midnight Sun*, a retelling of the first *Twilight* novel from Edward Cullen's perspective
- EL James wrote *Grey*, *Darker*, and *Freed*, retellings of the *Fifty Shades* trilogy from the perspective of Christian Grey

Compared to that, taking a subplot and transporting it into a different genre and setting isn't *that* lazy, and there shouldn't be a problem with it.